# How to remove leading space when printing with write?

Tags: fortran, fortran95

Suppose I have the following code

```
program fortran
  open(900, FILE='SOMETHING')   
  write(900, *) '21'    
end program fortran
```

The file form will be

```
 21
```

that is, there is a space before the number. How to get rid of that space?

Comment: In general, if you want control over formatting, you have to use formatted output, rather than unformatted/default formatting (eg, `*`).

Comment: Questions about list-directed IO not having the desired output are common.   As already answered, use formatted IO instead.

Answer (score 13):

You can write it as a string:

```
PROGRAM fortran 

  OPEN(900,FILE='SOMETHING')
  WRITE(900,'(a)') '21'

END PROGRAM FORTRAN
```

```
> cat SOMETHING 
21
```

---

To respond to the comment:

The more explicit way of doing that would be to write the number into a string (you could also use list-directed I/O for this step), remove whitespaces from the string [`trim`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/TRIM.html) and finally output the left-adjusted [`adjustl`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ADJUSTL.html):

```
program test
  character(len=23) :: str

  write(str,'(ES23.15 E3)') 1.23d0
  write(*,'(a)') adjustl(trim(str))

  write(str,'(ES14.7 E2)') 0.12e0
  write(*,'(a)') adjustl(trim(str))
end program
```

```
> ./a.out 
1.230000000000000E+000 
1.2000000E-01
```

This solution is probably more complicated then necessary, but it is a very flexible approach that can be extended easily for arbitrary purposes and formats.

Comment: I want to remove the leading space in real values also.

Comment: us a zero field width, eg. `write(*,'(f0.4)')3.14`

Answer (score 4):

In list-directed format (the `*` in `write(unit,*)`) the compiler typically inserts a leading space. The first column used to be used to control [line printers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_printer) but that is now deleted from Fortran.

You can use any explicit format you want to get rid of the leading space. For example the general `g0` one or the string specific `a` or the integer-specific `i`.